# Uploads by Date

Tags: file-upload

I need to manage files uploaded by people according to date, and make these files available for download. I need to keep only files for upto one month as there will be heavy files clean up is necessary. Can someone provide me a code snippet to guide me in the correct direction. I have not decided on a back end language yet so ASP or JSP will do.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a pseudo:

```
for each file
    if file is more than one month old
        delete file
```

Run this as hourly background job or something. Since you're not language-specific, I can't give a language-specific answer. I will however note that such a job doesn't belong in the view side (ASP/JSP), but rather in the backend (C#/Java).